# Call to undefined function Illuminate\Encryption\openssl_cipher_iv_length() - linux

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel 11, open_ssl подключен и работает.
Мало того, работает даже вывод

```
$method = 'AES-128-CBC';
$ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($method);
echo $ivlen;
```

Работает и выводит 16.
composer update делал.
Но ошибка "Call to undefined function Illuminate\Encryption\openssl_cipher_iv_length()" всё равно есть

Comment: Если функция не найдена, то и никакого 16 не будет выводиться. Где тот код, который вызывает эту ошибку?

Comment: В общем почему то artisan берёт конфигурацию php.ini не из каталога по умолчанию "/etc/php/8.2/cli/php.ini", а пытается найти в каталоге "/etc/php/8.2/cli-server/". Как это исправить, пока не понимаю. Если без artisan, то соответственно php видит open_ssl и функция нормально работает.

Answer (score 0):

Решение оказалось простым. Нужно было скопировать файлы из каталога "/etc/php/8.2/cli" в каталог "/etc/php/8.2/cli-server/"(его нужно перед этим создать). После данных манипуляций, artisan видит openssl и всё работает.